# Error creating parser in readHTMLTable

Tags: r, dataset

readHTMLTable seems pretty robust, but when I try to use it on this page, I get an error.

Any ideas what it means or how I could get around it?  The page's biggest table is nested inside another table... is that a problem?

```
> tables<-readHTMLTable(myURL, header=NA,a.data.frame=TRUE)
Error in htmlParse(doc) : 
  error in creating parser for http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/lproks.cgi
```

Comment: Move to StackOverflow?

Comment: I think it is Ok to answer this question here. We do have a `R` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table in question seems to need use of a Javascript button to download.  If you just want this particular data then save it as the offered *untitle.txt* or something else (it is basically tab-delimited) and then

```
tables           <- read.delim("untitle.txt", skip=1)
colnames(tables) <- c(colnames(tables)[-1],"junk")
tables$junk      <- NULL
```

seems to give you what I believe you want. The second and third lines of the R code are to deal with "## Columns:" which starts the second line of the file and upsets *read.delim()* when trying to get the column names.

Comment: wow thanks - that was it - i hadn't even considered the possibility :)